# Withdrawing from already deployed smart contract

Tags: remix, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, scam

First, I am sorry to say I have no knowledge in crypto nor coding, and in need of your help.

I have followed steps on this YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhkb9G2SyVw&ab_channel=Web3Tutorials

This was the pastebin link for the code: (description now shows a different one, although can't really see the difference)

https://pastebin.com/raw/efuJ1bAJ

First, I pasted the code in RemixIDE and deployed the contract, funded it with a very small amount(0.05ETH) to test things out. Ran code for about 24hr and actually made profit, successfully withdrew all funds in my wallet. Next I funded it with about 1ETH, although the code didn't work properly and gave me an error, something like (Gas Estimation Error, fund the contract with more ETH or wait for the market to cool down). I did some research and became aware of MevBot scams, and found out this was exactly what I was doing. Since it worked properly on the first run, I can't even tell if this is a scam or not.

When I check the smart contract address that I deployed, it still has the balance I funded. Is there a way to withdraw this to my wallet?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: This is my smart contract, if that provides any information.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xed2075a4777266cd9453e6a0c0e4019105567d34

Comment: you can try calling `withdrawal` with high gas fees in metamask

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that in detail? I'm sorry I barely know anything...

Comment: when you click on withdrawal button on Remix, Metamask opens.. There before confirming, you can click on fees and set it to 'aggressive' which means 'high'